# DocuSign API - JWT token generation

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Regarding API call to DocuSign with JWT token,

Can I use my own private key to generate JWT token and share my public key to DocuSign to decode the JWT?

if so, what algorithm to use?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use your own Private Key. You have to use DocuSign provided private Key for JWT authentication.

Comment: Thanks Amit K BIst. Just curious, if we insist DocuSIgn to let us use our private key and public key, Can DocuSign support this by customizing the authentication part for us?

Comment: No, currently there is no provision to use customer's Private Key for JWT. But as Larry suggested if you want to pursue then you can pursue it with his shared ticket number. But can you please share why you do not want to use DocuSign provided Private Key. Once you generate Private-Public Key pair in DocuSign, then DocuSign never uses your Private Key, it is for the customer use only.

Answer (score 1):

We have no support in DocuSign JWT for using a customer's public/private keypair. In April, 2019, the product group examined the issue and decided that other feature requests are of higher priority.

If you would like us to look at the idea again, please ask your DocuSign sales person to refer to internal ticket ID-2188.